# Battery Swapping in Electric Cars

Tags: mechanical-engineering

What are the advantages and disadvantages (technical, financial etc.) of having battery swapping system over charging stations for electric cars? As per my reading, battery swapping seems feasible for electric buses and 2-wheelers but not for cars. Is that really the case?

Also, is it possible for the battery to be housed under the bonnet instead of having it under the floor of the car so as to do away with underground swapping (like the one showcased by Tesla)? I know that the battery is placed there so as to lower the center of gravity. However, if there aren't any other significant benefits, can the aforementioned be done and battery swapping be made easier?